# Juego online - 1 vs 1 (IONIC 3 & ANGULAR 5)

Tags: ionic3, angular5, google-play, slim

¿Alguien me podría orientar un poco en como se podría plantear el jugar online desde mi aplicación?

He estado buscando cosas pero no me es posible encontrar algo con el que se plantee algo similar o algo que se le acerque un poquito a lo que deseo llegar a hacer.

Básicamente es un botón que quiero que haga que detecte si está conectado alguien y que busque entre todos los usuarios disponibles en ese momento y o que no se encuentren en partida, y a partir de ahí poder hacer todo lo relacionado con las partidas.

Tengo unos puntos que sobretodo son los que mas duda tengo...

-¿Cómo detecto si un usuario está activo en mi aplicación?
-¿Cómo detectar si el usuario se ha desconectado en mi aplicación?
-¿Cómo se consigue el hacer que en un botón busque una partida online, con los usuarios que estén disponibles?
-¿Cómo contemplar que si un jugador está en partida ya para que, no aparezca en varias partidas? (Aunque esté creo que es más sencillo, si es que consigo hacer todos los pasos anteriores)

Si alguien me puede orientar un poquito me sería muy útil su ayuda...
(Mi objetivo final también es llegar a poder subir el juego creado a Play Store), aunque no sé si eso servirá de información útil para ayudarme

¡Gracias de antemano!

Comment: en tu db podrias agregar un campo : conectado dando un 1 si esta conectado y un 0 si no, lo mismo, en el mismo campo si el usuario esta jugando colocas un 2 por ende si el usuario conectado == 1 es posible buscar juego de otra forma.... ya sabes desconectado o jugando

Comment: Correcto, y como se detectaría si el usuario está conectado o no? ¿Hay alguna manera de saber si está abierta la aplicación o cerrada? Para así cambiar el estado de conectado según si está conectado o no conectado

Comment: hacer una consulta a la db y saber todos los que tengan estado conectado==1, eso se en mi caso lo haría mediante ajax pero todos tienen sus técnicas, por ejemplo yo no se trabajar con angular 5 debe existir una manera, también en react hay otra manera...

Comment: por ende cada vez que un usuario busque una partida tendrías que hacer una función asincronica mediante ajax para hacer una consulta en la bd y traer de vuelta el resultado de quien esta conectado y quien no.

Comment: Creo que he pillado ya toda la lógica más o menos, cuando se pulsa el "boton", pongo a ese usuario en conectado y en disponible para jugar y que busque a otro que esté igual, y si no que aparezca no conectado para buscar partida aunque el usuario pueda estar conectado, revisando el ranking por ejemplo, pero en ese momento no está conectado para jugar una partida ...  (Creo que me he explicado un poco lioso) de todas maneras muchas gracias!

Comment: deje la respuesta completa mas abajo, saludos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

en tu db podrias agregar un campo : conectado dando un 1 si esta conectado y un 0 si no, lo mismo, en el mismo campo si el usuario esta jugando colocas un 2 por ende si el usuario conectado == 1 es posible buscar juego de otra forma.... ya sabes desconectado o jugando.
hacer una consulta a la db y saber todos los que tengan estado conectado==1, eso se en mi caso lo haría mediante ajax pero todos tienen sus técnicas, por ejemplo yo no se trabajar con angular 5 debe existir una manera, también en react hay otra manera...por ende cada vez que un usuario busque una partida tendrías que hacer una función asincronica mediante ajax para hacer una consulta en la bd y traer de vuelta el resultado de quien esta conectado y quien no.

En mi caso el ajax json.html es ya el listado completo de todos los usuarios con la consulta ya hecha que trae una tabla con los que conectado = 1 y le haces un append a algun div asi:

**AJAX**

```
   $("#buscarUsers").on("click", function() {
      var formData = new FormData();
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "api/buscar_usuarios",
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: formData,
        success: function(json) {
          if (json.success == 1) {
          $('#algundiv').append(json.html);
          } else {
            msg_box_alert(json.success, "Error", json.message);
          }
        },
        error: function(xhr, status) {
          msg_box_alert(99, "Error", xhr.responseText);
        }
      });
    });
```